# 3D Data to bvh file

Tags: blender, azurekinect

I use 3D data recorded via an Azure Kinect camera. I extracted the body joints and now I want to bring it to blender to animate a rig. For this I am trying to generate a bvh file in Python - so far the hierarchy looks more or less good (also in Blender) but I think I struggling with the MOTION part. Here is my question, I can not really find any clear instructions: what does the Motion part of an bvh file contain? Simply the global coordinates? I read something like "the translation/ rotation vectors". Do I have to calculate the translation vectors and put them in the motion part?

I tried the global coordinate and I calculated the translation vectors. Both didn't work properly ...